# System.Net.Mail - Sending two emails?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, smtp

Using the following function:

```
Public Sub SendMail(ByVal SendFrom As String, ByVal SendTo As String, ByVal Subject As String, ByVal Body As String)

    Dim client As New SmtpClient
    Dim message As New MailMessage

    message.Body = Body
    message.Subject = Subject
    message.From = New MailAddress(SendFrom)
    message.To.Add(New MailAddress(SendTo))

    client.Port = "25"
    client.Host = "smtp.myserver.com"

    client.Send(message)

End Sub
```

I call it with

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

    Dim iandamsb As New StringBuilder

    iandamsb.AppendLine("Please make the following changes:")
    iandamsb.AppendLine("")
    iandamsb.AppendLine("Current name:" & txtCurrentName.Text)
    iandamsb.AppendLine("New name:" & txtNewName.Text)
    iandamsb.AppendLine("New username:" & txtNewUsername.Text)
    iandamsb.AppendLine("Applications:" & txtOtherApplications.Text)

    Dim iandambody As String = iandamsb.ToString

    SendMail(txtRequesterEmail.Text, "ayockel@mydomain.com", "Name Change Request - " & txtCurrentName.Text, iandambody)

End Sub
```

It works just fine, however it is sending two emails instead of one.  Can anyone figure out why it's sending a duplicate?

Comment: Where does the calling code get executed? Can you put a breakpoint on the first line of sendmail and debug through it?

Comment: may be your function is called twice ?

Comment: The problem is probably in the calling code, not here. Could you display/comment that part of code?

Comment: SendMail(txtRequesterEmail.text, "myemail@domain.com", "Name Change", "Body of email")
is the calling code.  There is nothing else.

Comment: how you are calling SendMail function ? Any event handler (Button )  Or Page Load event, post that code

Comment: Sorry, I have not explained well myself. Your call to SendMail is probably inside to an event, like a page postback, a button_click or something. I was interested in that, the chain of code that leads to the calling SendMail.

Comment: Ah, you're right it's probably something along those lines. I've posted the full code.

Comment: I would guess that your button thinks its getting clicked twice. Do you have the event bound to it twice? (Event bound to the button via `Handles btnSubmit.Click` and button bound to the event via `OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"`?). I would search your code for "btnSubmit_Click" and see if it's used somewhere else it shouldn't.

Comment: Simply use the breakpoint counter and see how many times does your function get called. If it's called twice (and apparently, we all believe it is), this code is just fine, the problem is in something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would venture to guess that you have the button click event bound *twice*: once through an `OnClick` attribute in the markup:

```
<asp:Button OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" runat="server" ... />
```

and then again through the code-behind via `Handles`:

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) 
    Handles btnSubmit.Click
```

I would remove one of them if that's the case. I would keep the latter so you know that the `btnSubmit_Click` event is properly wired at compile time.

[A discussion of this issue](http://weblogs.asp.net/nannettethacker/archive/2008/02/19/onclick-and-handles-caution.aspx).